# "Shadow" Option isnt showing in the Lightning Settings

Tags: shadows

Im using the latest Blender version and if I wanna configure my shadow options it doesnt show where its supposed to be as you can see in the picture. I remember thats its been working in the past so Im pretty sure I just did something to hide it but I cant figure out what it is. Id appreciate help a lot!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you click on Light (in the Object Data Properties), you can then uncheck the Cast Shadow box. Alternatively you could select an individual object, go to Object properties, click on Visibility and uncheck the Shadow box. All this applies to Cycles, found in Render Properties > Render Engine.

If you set the Render Engine to EEVEE in the Render Properties, then you can click on Shadows a bit below it. Also then there is a Shadow section in the Object Data Properties if you select a light.

All these settings can be found in the Properties window.

EDIT: (as promised in comments)

If light goes down, shadow becomes longer:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped!
Nevertheless, the shadow are still being really "small". I tried changing the position of the lightning source but it didnt really change anything, can I fix that somehow?

Comment: The surface of a shadow is bigger if the light source is closer (in terms of height) to the object casting the shadow, I don't  think there is any other way a shadow can be smaller or bigger. I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Comment: I added a picture in the original post of how it looks for me rn.
If I deactivate Cast Shadows, I can see a difference but turning it on isnt as effective as it is in your picture for example

Comment: The darkness or brightness of a shadow depends on many things. But I think it might help you if you change the Size of your light (it represents the Shadow Soft Size). From your screenshot i can see it is 15 m. The the light I used is the light from start up file, and had a Size of 0.1 m. I think you'll get a better re result if you make it smaller. (If that doesn't help, open the start up file, select the Light, press Ctrl + C, open your file, press Ctrl + V, and see if that light is better)

Comment: Ahhh alright, that was the problem. Thank you so much man I really do appreciate your help!